# nltk is installed but still getting error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk

i m writing code in jupyter  and getting the following error. i have installed nltk thoroughly by http://www.nltk.org/ .Please share your wisdom, i'd really appreciate your response.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2c19d039acfb> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 import nltk
      5 import os
      6 import nltk.corpus

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

Comment: How did you install nltk? If you were using sudo, please try installing it using pip3 install nltk.

Comment: I installed using anaconda prompt (cmd) .

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you have two Python installed and you installed module in one Python but you run code with other Python. If you run Jupyter with command `python -m jupyter notebook` then you could use the same `python` to install module `python -m pip install nltk` to make sure it install in correct Python.

Comment: Check which environment you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

you should install NLTK on its on then install the needed packages of NLTK independent.